# Format phone numbers leaving only alphanumeric characters and then follow a format

Tags: vba, excel

It's my first time posting here. I am currently exploring VBA and I wanted to make a macro that formats phone numbers and translates it into a standard format. All special characters other that numbers and letters should be removed. I'm so sorry for my english is not that good. Here is an example.

The scenario must look like this, I select a range,

```
8009228080

(900) (CAT) BABA

(+1) (900) (289) (9000)

900.900.9000
```

then I click the button where the macro is assigned then it goes like this

```
800-922-8080

900-228-2222

900-289-9000

900-900-9000
```

The output must be only ###-###-#### (3 numbers ' - ' 3 numbers ' - ' 4 numbers)
Letter must be translated into following
ABC = 2, DEF = 3, GHI = 4, JKL = 5, MNO = 6, PQRS = 7, TUV = 8, WXYZ = 9
I tried looking it up and here is my try:

```
    Sub PhoneFormat()

    Dim StSel As Range
    Dim EndSel As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    xTitleId = "Format Phone Numbers"
    Set EndSel = Application.Selection
    Set EndSel = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, EndSel.Address, Type:=8)
```

*I want to change this part as I want to select the range first, then click the button then the macro is applied*

```
    For Each StSel In EndSel

        StSel.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(StSel.Value, "+", "")
        StSel.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(StSel.Value, "+1", "")
        StSel.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(StSel.Value, "-", "")
        StSel.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(StSel.Value, ".", "")
        StSel.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(StSel.Value, "(", "")
        StSel.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(StSel.Value, ")", "")
        StSel.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(StSel.Value, " ", "")

        If (Len(StSel) > 10) Then
            StSel = Right(StSel, 10)
        End If


    StSel = Left(StSel, 3) & "-" & Mid(StSel, 4, 3) & "-" & Right(StSel, 4)


    Next
    End Sub
```

I think this could be optimized into much simplier code but I can't do it. This code also can't replace letters to numbers. Thanks in advance an I hope anyone would answer this.

Comment: What you want to format this `(900) (CAT) BABA` into?

Comment: I would remove all not allowed digits (here the hardest to remove will be the country codes I guess), then I would translate all characters into numbers, so all entries should be 11 digits only. And at last I would insert the dashes. Or you use regular expressions to recognize all different possibilities of entered formats and then you just need to translate characters into numbers additionally.

Comment: @0m3r from the example ABC = 2, DEF = 3, GHI = 4, JKL = 5, MNO = 6, PQRS = 7, TUV = 8, WXYZ = 9. [Phonewords](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoneword)

Comment: Thanks @dadler I'm soryy I didnt included it in my post

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I was trying to format and change the cell values into 10 characters only that's why I included 
      "  If (Len(StSel) > 10) Then
            StSel = Right(StSel, 10)
        End If  "
the count starts from the right since that country codes/area codes are located in the left part of the number

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example how you could do it with Regular Expressions:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()
    Debug.Print FormatWithRegEx("(900) (CAT) BABA")
    Debug.Print FormatWithRegEx("(+1) (900) (289) (9000)")
    Debug.Print FormatWithRegEx("900.900.9000")

    Debug.Print ReplaceCharactersWithRegEx(FormatWithRegEx("(900) (CAT) BABA")) 
    'or dircetly implement ReplaceCharactersWithRegEx in FormatWithRegEx
End Sub

Public Function FormatWithRegEx(InputString As String) As String
    Dim objRegEx As Object
    Set objRegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    Dim arrPatterns() As Variant
    arrPatterns = Array( _
        "([A-Z0-9]{10})", _
        "\(?([A-Z0-9]{3})\)? \(?([A-Z0-9]{3})\)? \(?([A-Z0-9]{4})\)?", _
        "([A-Z0-9]{3})\.([A-Z0-9]{3})\.([A-Z0-9]{4})" _
    )

    Dim Pattern As Variant
    For Each Pattern In arrPatterns
        With objRegEx
            .Global = True
            .IgnoreCase = True
            .MultiLine = False
            .Pattern = Pattern

            Dim objMatches As Object
            Set objMatches = .Execute(InputString)
        End With

        If objMatches.Count = 1 Then
            With objMatches(0)
                If .SubMatches.Count = 3 Then
                    FormatWithRegEx= .SubMatches(0) & "-" & .SubMatches(1) & "-" & .SubMatches(2)
                End If
            End With
        End If
        If FormatWithRegEx <> vbNullString Then Exit For
    Next Pattern
    'to implement ReplaceCharactersWithRegEx uncomment …
    'FormatWithRegEx = ReplaceCharactersWithRegEx(FormatWithRegEx)
End Function
```

It recognizes the 3 given patterns in the test. Translation from characters into numbers still has to be done.

Here is a pure RegEx Replace example

```
Public Function ReplaceCharactersWithRegEx(InputString As String) As String
    InputString = RegExReplace(InputString, "[ABC]{1}", "2")
    InputString = RegExReplace(InputString, "[DEF]{1}", "3")
    InputString = RegExReplace(InputString, "[GHI]{1}", "4")
    InputString = RegExReplace(InputString, "[JKL]{1}", "5")
    InputString = RegExReplace(InputString, "[MNO]{1}", "6")
    InputString = RegExReplace(InputString, "[PQRS]{1}", "7")
    InputString = RegExReplace(InputString, "[TUV]{1}", "8")
    InputString = RegExReplace(InputString, "[WXYZ]{1}", "9")

    ReplaceCharactersWithRegEx = InputString
End Function

Private Function RegExReplace(InputString, Pattern, Replace) As String
    Dim objRegEx As Object
    Set objRegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    With objRegEx
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .MultiLine = False
        .Pattern = Pattern

        Dim objMatches As Object
        Set objMatches = .Execute(InputString)
    End With

    RegExReplace = objRegEx.Replace(InputString, Replace)
End Function
```

//Edit
made it case insensitive with `.IgnoreCase = True`

//Edit2
**A Selection Loop Example**

```
Dim cl As Range
For Each cl In Selection 'instead of Selection you can also use a defined Range("A1:A50")
    Dim FormattedValue As String
    FormattedValue = FormatWithRegEx(cl.value)
    If FormattedValue <> vbNullString Then 'don't delete if formatting wasn't successful
        cl.value = FormatWithRegEx(cl.value)
    End If
Next cl
```

Comment: Hi @PEH ! Sorry if you're about to spoon feed me. But if I'm going to run this and make the code apply to the selection (highlighted), what part should I change? If I added ReplaceCharactersWithRegEx function, would the conversion of letters to numbers be applied? I also edited my post and put another example. TIA!

Comment: @LeggoDave You will need to write your own sub that loops through that selected range and then call the `FormatWithRegEx` function for each cell. Yes the conversion of letters to numbers will be applied. You need to know all possible input formats and find a pattern for it. A computer can only find what someone teached him to find. I added an example for a loop.

Comment: Good day @PEH! I've tried running your code and it perfectly works with the examples I had included in my post and the like. However, for some number formats, it won't work -- it gets deleted. Even when I tried applying the macro to 'perfectly fine' format, it gets deleted. For example, when I tried applying the macro to "900-900-9000", it gets deleted. When I tried it to an example "(+1) (900) (289) (9000)" it works perfectly fine, but when I tried it to "+1 (900) 982 8728" it gets deleted. I hope you're still with me :)

Comment: Of course as I told you it can only recognize these input formats that you teach your algorithm by adding a pattern for it. So you will need to add a pattern for **every** type of input format. I added an example how you prevent already correct (and incorrect input format) entries from being deleted. Also added a pattern for +1 (900) 982 8728

Comment: I removed 2 patterns and changed it into a more flexible one `\(?([A-Z0-9]{3})\)? \(?([A-Z0-9]{3})\)? \(?([A-Z0-9]{4})\)?` which accepts all `### ### ####` (3 digits, 3 digits, 4 digits) divided by spaces and with or without brackets. You can use [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/GKLmWW/1) to test and build new patterns yourself.

Comment: Using RegEx101 is too hard :( I don't want to discontinue this but I'm having a hard time haha but I'm pushing through

Comment: @LeggoDave I know RegEx might look hard at first, but the task in your question is not trivial too, so hard questions need mighty tools. It would be harder doing it without regex I think.

Answer (score 1):

Taking PEH's answer and adding the Conversion of Letters to Numbers:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Set rng = Selection
For Each cell In rng
    cell.Value = ConvertLetters(FormatWithRegEx(cell.Value))
Next
End Sub

Public Function ConvertLetters(FormattedString As String) As String
    Dim J As Long, Digit As Variant
    For J = 1 To Len(FormattedString)
        Digit = UCase(Mid(FormattedString, J, 1))
        Select Case Digit
            Case "A" To "P"
                Digit = Chr((Asc(Digit) + 1) \ 3 + 28)
            Case "Q"
                Digit = "7"
            Case "R" To "Y"
                Digit = Chr(Asc(Digit) \ 3 + 28)
            Case "Z"
                Digit = "9"
        End Select
        Mid(FormattedString, J, 1) = Digit
    Next J
ConvertLetters = FormattedString
End Function


Public Function FormatWithRegEx(InputString As String) As String
    Dim objRegEx As Object
    Set objRegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    Dim arrPatterns() As Variant
    arrPatterns = Array( _
        "\(([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})\) \(([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})\) ([a-zA-Z0-9]{4})", _
        "\(([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})\) \(([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})\) \(([a-zA-Z0-9]{4})\)", _
        "([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})\.([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})\.([a-zA-Z0-9]{4})" _
    )

    Dim Pattern As Variant
    For Each Pattern In arrPatterns
        With objRegEx
            .Global = True
            .IgnoreCase = True
            .MultiLine = False
            .Pattern = Pattern

            Dim objMatches As Object
            Set objMatches = .Execute(InputString)
        End With

        If objMatches.Count = 1 Then
            With objMatches(0)
                If .SubMatches.Count = 3 Then
                    FormatWithRegEx = .SubMatches(0) & "-" & .SubMatches(1) & "-" & .SubMatches(2)
                End If
            End With
        End If
        If FormatWithRegEx <> vbNullString Then Exit For
    Next Pattern

End Function
```

**UPDATE:**

The following will format your phone numbers as expressed in your comments (taking Thom's answer and adding the Selection):

```
Sub PhoneFormat()
Dim myLen As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim myNum As String
Dim newNum
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Set rng = Selection
For Each cell In rng
    '   Loop through characters, converting values
        If Len(cell.Value) > 0 Then
            For i = 1 To Len(cell.Value)
                Select Case Mid(cell.Value, i, 1)
                    Case "0"
                        myNum = "0"
                    Case "1"
                        myNum = "1"
                    Case "2"
                        myNum = "2"
                    Case "3"
                        myNum = "3"
                    Case "4"
                        myNum = "4"
                    Case "5"
                        myNum = "5"
                    Case "6"
                        myNum = "6"
                    Case "7"
                        myNum = "7"
                    Case "8"
                        myNum = "8"
                    Case "9"
                        myNum = "9"

                    Case "A", "B", "C", "a", "b", "c"
                        myNum = "2"
                    Case "D", "E", "F", "d", "e", "f"
                        myNum = "3"
                    Case "G", "H", "I", "g", "h", "i"
                        myNum = "4"
                    Case "J", "K", "L", "j", "k", "l"
                        myNum = "5"
                    Case "M", "N", "O", "m", "n", "o"
                        myNum = "6"
                    Case "P", "Q", "R", "S", "p", "q", "r", "s"
                        myNum = "7"
                    Case "T", "U", "V", "t", "u", "v"
                        myNum = "8"
                    Case "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "w", "x", "y", "z"
                        myNum = "9"

                    Case " ", "-", "."
                        myNum = "-"

                    Case Else
                        myNum = ""
                End Select
                newNum = newNum & myNum
            Next i
        End If
    cell.Value = Right(newNum, 12)
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @Xabier ! I'm a bit confused as how to run your code and PEH's. I'm dearly sorry. I included in the post that I would like the VBA code to be applied to a selection. Would you mind helping me on how to run this code and making this to be applied to a selection?

Comment: @LeggoDave, I've updated my answer to reflect your comments, it will now run and update the selected range. :)

Comment: dear, @Xabier. As I was executing your code, I've noticed that it is perfectly working with the given examples. However, I was looking to find a way to translate almost all possible formats that are to be encountered into 'three'-'three'-'four'. I tried your code with these examples
'+1 (900) 982 8728 |
(900) 982 8728 |
900 900 9829 |
ABC.DEF.GHIJ |

Some didn't worked out and just got deleted. I've also noticed that if this code is applied to those phone numbers which are already in correct format, they get deleted. I hope you still got me even this time :)

Comment: @LeggoDave, I've updated my answer to reflect your new comments, this will now take your selection and format phone numbers including the ones you mentioned in your comment. Hope this helps... :)

Comment: Hi @Xabier thanks for helping out! I've removed some of the codes to make it more flexible Case " ", "-", "."
                        myNum = "-"
However, the case now is that only the number values are left, and no fomatting. For this case, i tried applying the right, left, and, mid feature,
    If (Len(newNum) > 10) Then
        newNum = Right(newNum, 10)
    End If
    

        newNum = Left(newNum, 3) & "-" & Mid(newNum, 4, 3) & "-" & Right(newNum, 4)

but the value seems not to be passed to _newNum_ Have I written this right?

Answer (score 0):

I have now amended the script to work with a selected range and it will also convert all given examples.

It is simple to read and amend for other purposes which maybe useful to somebody, that is why I am posting it.

The script uses Case Else to remove characters that are not defined, converting the ones that are required.

```
Sub PhoneFormatRange()

        Dim myLen As Long
        Dim i As Long

        Dim myNum As String
        Dim newNum As String

        Dim selectedRng As Range
        Dim celRng As Range

        Dim strLeft As String
        Dim strMid As String
        Dim strRight As String


    ' Find the Selected Range and for each cell in the selected range run the cade and repeat.
    Set selectedRng = Application.Selection
    For Each celRng In selectedRng.Cells


    ' Convert Cell value to an array
    myLen = Len(celRng.Value)

    ReDim Carray(Len(celRng.Value))

    For i = 0 To myLen
        Carray(i) = Mid(celRng.Value, i + 1, 1)
    Next

    '   Loop through array, converting values
        If myLen > 0 Then
            For i = 0 To myLen
                Select Case Carray(i)
                     Case "0"
                        myNum = "0"
                    Case "1"
                        myNum = "1"
                    Case "2"
                        myNum = "2"
                    Case "3"
                        myNum = "3"
                    Case "4"
                        myNum = "4"
                    Case "5"
                        myNum = "5"
                    Case "6"
                        myNum = "6"
                    Case "7"
                        myNum = "7"
                    Case "8"
                        myNum = "8"
                    Case "9"
                        myNum = "9"

                    Case "A", "B", "C", "a", "b", "c"
                        myNum = "2"
                    Case "D", "E", "F", "d", "e", "f"
                        myNum = "3"
                    Case "G", "H", "I", "g", "h", "i"
                        myNum = "4"
                    Case "J", "K", "L", "j", "k", "l"
                        myNum = "5"
                    Case "M", "N", "O", "m", "n", "o"
                        myNum = "6"
                    Case "P", "Q", "R", "S", "p", "q", "r", "s"
                        myNum = "7"
                    Case "T", "U", "V", "t", "u", "v"
                        myNum = "8"
                    Case "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "w", "x", "y", "z"
                        myNum = "9"

                    Case " ", "-", "."
                        myNum = "-"

                    Case Else
                        myNum = ""

                End Select

                newNum = newNum & myNum
            Next i
        End If


    ' Check the length of the string and if it requals 10 then add the hypens
    If Len(newNum) = 10 Then

        strLeft = Left(newNum, 3)
        strMid = Mid(newNum, 4, 3)
        strRight = Right(newNum, 4)

        newNum = strLeft & "-" & strMid & "-" & strRight

    End If

    ' Set the cell value within the range to 12 right most characters of the string
    celRng.Value = Right(newNum, 12)


    ' Clear newNum before repeating
    newNum = ""

    ' Go back to celRng and repeat until all the cells within the selection is complete
    Next celRng

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @Thom! I don't know if I executed your code properly but it seems that the code only applies to the first cell in the selection. The formatting seems to be a little different when I applied it to one of the examples I included in the post

Comment: This will not work on the Selected range as you used ActiveCell, you could change that bit to include the Selected Range instead of ActiveCell...

Comment: I was ment to have put cell, not range. I have edited my answer to show this.

Comment: This code worked with your original examples, since I added this answer there has been an extra sample of data added to your original question, that is why it does not work as you want. This code may still be useful for someone else even it is still does not fully meet your requirements

Comment: Hi LeggoDave, I have amended the script to work with a range and also convert all your sample data, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was also writing a regular expression as PEH did. But my approach was a bit different. Only posting it because it was fun to code this piece and it maybe helps. 
I also used Xabiers ConvertLetters function because it does a good job and the code is a really good approach.

My approach to the regular expression was to match ALL criterias in one expression. So the pattern I defined finds all your defined possibilities. This forced me to make some extra replacements though so I extended Xabiers code a bit.

```
Sub correctNumbers()
Dim i As Long, J As Long
Dim sEXP As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim oRegEx As Object, oMatch As Object
  ' create object for regular expressions
  Set oRegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
  ' supposed you have a sheet called "Sheet1" - change sheetname and range according to your needs
  Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A4")

  ' run through every entry in range
  For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
    With oRegEx
      .Global = True
      .IgnoreCase = False
      ' define pattern as desribed by you needs
      .Pattern = "([\(]?[0-9]{3}[\)]?[\s\.]?[\(]?[A-Z0-9]{3}[\)]?[\s\.]?[\(]?[A-Z0-9]{4}[\)]?)"
      Set oMatch = .Execute(rng(i, 1).Value)
      If oMatch.Count <> 0 Then
        sEXP = oMatch(0)
        If Len(sEXP) = 10 Then
          sEXP = Left(sEXP, 3) & "-" & Right(Left(sEXP, 6), 3) & "-" & Right(sEXP, 4)
        Else
          sEXP = ConvertLetters(oMatch(0))
        End If
      Else
        sEXP = ""
      End If
    End With
    ' write result in column B
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i + 1).Value = sEXP
  Next i
End Sub

 Public Function ConvertLetters(FormattedString As String) As String
 Dim J As Long, Digit As Variant
 For J = 1 To Len(FormattedString)
   Digit = UCase(Mid(FormattedString, J, 1))
   Select Case Digit
     Case "A" To "P"
       Digit = Chr((Asc(Digit) + 1) \ 3 + 28)
     Case "Q"
       Digit = "7"     'May want to change
     Case "R" To "Y"
       Digit = Chr(Asc(Digit) \ 3 + 28)
     Case "Z"
       Digit = "9"     'May want to change
       ' added as my regular expression finds complete number including dots, spaces and braces
     Case ".", " "
       Digit = "-"
     End Select
     Mid(FormattedString, J, 1) = Digit
   Next J
   ' added repalce as my regular expression finds complete number including dots, spaces and braces
   ConvertLetters = Replace(Replace(FormattedString, "(", ""), ")", "")
End Function
```

Comment: Hi @TXP I would like to ask if there is a way to change the range from "Range("A2:A4")" to a selection? For instance, this VBA code applies to a highlighted part. Additionally, the number does not format if there are no spaces in between numbers. For example, 9008992030 does not change to 900-899-2030. And can it be possible that the formatted phone number be on the part of the selection? Let's say that I selected A1:A10 then the formatting result would be on the same selection. This was very helpful though!

Comment: To make this apply to your selected range simply replace `Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A4")` with `Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Selection`

Comment: Do I have to set the rng as selection? I'm having a difficulty sorry.

Comment: Hi @LeggoDave. You will have to change the code like Xabier suggested. Then it takes the current selection. So you'll first select the range A2:A100 and then run the macro.
And regarding the example that it doesn't set the dashes when the number is 9008992030 - it was no requirement in your initial question. ;)

Comment: Hi again. Just checked your question and found that you did ask for that number format. So I changed my code to add "-" to these numbers. The only change that needs to be done is after "If oMatch.Count <> 0 Then" line. Hope it helps.